# Ogre: simulating perspective view scaling object

Tags: c++, view, perspective, ogre

For my project Ogre in **c++**, I want to create an animation of an object using SimpleSpline of Ogre.
  Everything works perfectly, the object is animated along the sequence of points in the path correctly.
  
Since I need to use a scene with orthographic view, so no perspective, I would still simulate the effect depth "playing" on the scale of the object.

Thus, for each frame updating position and scale of the object in this way:

```
const Vector3 position = this->getPoint(index_, time_);
const float scale = 1 / (1 + position.z);
node_->setScale(scale, scale, scale);
node_->setPosition(position);
```

It works quite good. Is there a way to make the depth effect more realistic?

Comment: what do you mean with *a scene with viewing angles*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using DeflectorPlane in the script of your particle system.

[Here](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/manual/manual_40.html#DeflectorPlane-Affector) you can find the documentation and the usage.